# Wild card for java.sql.Types with Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, sql, oracle, blob, spring-jdbc

I want to insert a blob to a table in a oracle database. But I don't know the data types of the other columns. I want to pass values for other columns just in Object type.

I know I can use the following code to insert the blob value.

```
jdbcTemplate.update(
            "INSERT INTO LOB_ (BLOB_) VALUES (?)",
            new Object[]{new SqlLobValue(inputStream)},
            new int[]{Types.BLOB}
    );
```

But my problem is that, I don't know the types of the other columns. Then how can I specify the type in the type array as the third argument of the `update(query, args, typeArgs)` method.

Is there any value like a wild card to pass to tell the jdbctemplate to skip checking types for other columns?

I want something like this?

```
jdbcTemplate.update(
            "INSERT INTO LOB_ (BLOB_, NAME, AGE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
            new Object[]{new SqlLobValue(inputStream), "Some string", 34},
            new int[]{Types.BLOB, ?, ?}
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html

```
final File blobIn = new File("spring2004.jpg");
final InputStream blobIs = new FileInputStream(blobIn);
final File clobIn = new File("large.txt");
final InputStream clobIs = new FileInputStream(clobIn);
final InputStreamReader clobReader = new InputStreamReader(clobIs);
jdbcTemplate.execute(
    "INSERT INTO lob_table (id, a_clob, a_blob) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
    new AbstractLobCreatingPreparedStatementCallback(lobHandler) { 1
        protected void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, LobCreator lobCreator) throws SQLException {
            ps.setLong(1, 1L);
            lobCreator.setClobAsCharacterStream(ps, 2, clobReader, (int)clobIn.length()); 2
            lobCreator.setBlobAsBinaryStream(ps, 3, blobIs, (int)blobIn.length()); 3
        }
    }
);
blobIs.close();
clobReader.close();
```

Comment: This doesn't need the type as an argument. But here I cannot pass the set of values as an object array. I have to manually set the values to the prepared statement which is not possible in my case.